# Owncloud sync app LDAP authentication

Tags: php, mysql, ldap, webdav, owncloud

We're currently working on an external LDAP authentication for the owncloud sync app and webdav. While I'm able to authenticate with LDAP, I am unsure of how to login to owncloud without knowing the users owncloud password. I've been looking through the source code, but I can't find where login occurs in the LDAP module. We don't want to use the LDAP module that is included in owncloud.

Basically, I want to know if there is a way to retrieve an unencrypted password from the owncloud DB? If the encrypted password in the DB would work for logins? or if there is a way to login a user after LDAP authentication with only a username?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I want to know if there is a way to retrieve an unencrypted password from the owncloud DB? If the encrypted password in the DB would work for logins?

LDAP user passwords are not stored at all.

> I've been looking through the source code, but I can't find where login occurs in the LDAP module.

In ownCloud, the login credentials are passed to the checkPassword method of the registered user backend, which replies with false (not granted) or the username (= granted).

Comment: I realized that this was a dumb question after I asked it (getting unencrypted passwords from the db would defeat the purpose), still thank you for the explanation, hope it helps someone in the future.